# Find distinct number of elements in a comma-separated string in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a column with data type string in a BigQuery dataset with comma-separated products id:s a user purchased, and the column may very well contain duplicate id:s as the user can purchase several products of the same kind. I have been trying to find a convenient way to count the number of distinct product id:s in this string, but without success. Since column can contain duplicate values of product id:s, the ARRAY_LENGTH function would not work, and if possible, I would prefer a solution without the use of UDFs.

An example for reference. I have the user_id and the products column, and would like to create the column named distinct_product_count. We can give this table the name 'products' if you would like to refer to it in your example query!

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select *, 
  ( select count(distinct product)
    from unnest(split(products)) product
  ) as  distinct_product_count
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]